# How can I convert a std::process::Command into a command line string?

Tags: process, rust, command

For example:

```
let mut com = std::process::Command::new("ProgramA");

com.env("ENV_1", "VALUE_1")
    .arg("-a")
    .arg("foo")
    .arg("-b")
    .arg("--argument=bar");

// Get the command line string somehow here.

com.output().unwrap();
```

This will spawn a process with this command line `"ProgramA" -a foo -b "--argument=with space"` associated with it.

Is there a way to get this back out from the `com` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out `Command` implements `Debug`; this will give me the desired result:

```
let answer = format!("{:?}", com);
```