# How to format the std::process::Command as a string for debugging

Tags: rust

Working on my first rust app, and it issues a number of commands via `std::process::Command`. If one of these is incorrect I'd like to see what it is, and to have it look pretty on the command line.

Currently I have code that looks like this (simplified):

```rust
let mut command = std::process::Command::new("ls");
command.arg("-la");
println!("{:?}", command)
```

This is alright, but it encloses everything in quotes when it prints the string. The output looks like: `"ls" "-la"`.

How can I format this so that it doesn't enclose each arg in double quotes, but instead produces a command that is easy to read? Something like: `ls -la`.

I saw a [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716197/how-can-i-convert-a-stdprocesscommand-into-a-command-line-string), but it comes to the same mediocre solution.

Comment: "instead produces a command that could be copied and run?" On most Unix shells running `"ls" "-la"` should just work as is. On Windows `cmd.exe` escaping is a bit insane and things are more complicated.

Comment: I had no idea commands could be run like that. Very nice to know. I'd still prefer, for readability, that they were not quoted. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command adds the quotes because, while they're "ugly," they never break a command. On the other hand, not having them can!  Parsing whether you need them or not, including all edge cases, can get surprisingly complicated.

If you have a tightly controlled set of use cases, and you are certain that you don't need them, then just remove them:

```
let mut command = std::process::Command::new("ls");
command.arg("-la");
println!("{}", format!("{:?}", command).replace("\"", ""));
```